# vectorized / linear algebra distance between points?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have an array of points,

```
import numpy as np
pts = np.random.rand(100,3)  # 1000 points, X, Y, Z along second dimension
```

The naive approach to calculate the distance between each combination of points involves a double for loop and will be excruciatingly slow for large numbers of points,

```
def euclidian_distance(p1, p2):
    d = p2 - p1
    return np.sqrt(d**2).sum()

out = np.empty((pts.shape[0], pts.shape[0]))
pts_swapped = pts.swapaxes(0,1)
for idx, point in enumerate(pts_swapped):
    for idx2, point_inner in enumerate(pts_swapped):
        out[idx,idx2] = euclidian_distance(point, point_inner)
```

How do I vectorize this calculation?

Comment: Take a look at the [scipy.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) function. I'm not sure but i assume that scipy optimized this quite a lot. If you use the *pts* array for both inputs, I assume you'll get an M x M array with zeros on the diagonal .

Comment: Thank you!  If you submit this as an answer, I can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [scipy.spatial.distance.cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). I'm not sure but i assume that scipy optimized this quite a lot. If you use the pts array for both inputs, I assume you'll get an M x M array with zeros on the diagonal .  function

Comment: Might want to proofread this.  Looks like you duplicated a couple sentences.